# Is it possible to list nonexisting groups when using $group?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

If I want to perform a $group and $sum on a mongodb collection from my node server (using mongoosoe), is it possible to return 0 for the non existing groups?
the collection has the following fields: ssn, name, gender, city.

```
        model.aggregate([
        {
            $group : { _id : { city:"$city", gender:"$gender"}, count{ $sum:1 }}
        }], function (err,result) {
                if(err) {
                    //err
                }
                else{
                    //response
                }
        });
```

if there are people of both genders in the city - the query will return:

```
{
"_id" : {
    "city" : "NY",
    "gender" : "male"
},
"count" : 11
},
{
"_id" : {
    "city" : "NY",
    "gender" : "female"
},
"count" : 31
}
```

but if people of one gender are not present in a city - no value will be returned. for example no males in LA:

```
{
"_id" : {
    "city" : "LA",
    "gender" : "female"
},
"count" : 53
}
```

is it possible to make the query return the following result for given scenario without having a collection with cities and population quantities?

```
{
"_id" : {
    "city" : "LA",
    "gender" : "male"
},
"count" : 0
},    
{
"_id" : {
    "city" : "LA",
    "gender" : "female"
},
"count" : 53
}
```

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the possible values are finite and known as in your example, you could use **$cond** to combine the counts for male and female into one document per city like this:

```
[
    {
        $group : {
            _id: {
                city:"$city"
            }, 
            males:{
                $sum: {
                    $cond: {if: {$eq:["$gender", "male"]}, then: 1, else: 0}
                } 
            }, 
            females:{
                $sum: {
                    $cond: {if: {$eq:["$gender", "female"]}, then: 1, else: 0}
                } 
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and report back tomorrow.